# counting the number of times a button is pressed

Tags: javascript, html

I have to make a button that everytime it is clicked it adds one to the counter. SO counter would look like this. Counter: 0 and then once the button is clicked counter goes to one and so on. So far it only goes up to the number one.

my js code is:

```
var $ = function (id) { return document.getElementById(id); };
var counter;

function start(){

var button = document.getElementById("button");
window.addEventListener("click", count, false);

};
function count(){
counter = document.getElementById("counter");
counter = counter+1;

document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = counter;

};

window.addEventListener("load", start, false);
```

my html code is:

```
<html>

<head>

<title>12.5 valenti</title>


<meta charset = "uft-8">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="12.5.js"></script>
</head>



<body>

<div>
<p><input type = "button" id="button"  value = "button"></p>
<p> count:  <span id = "count">0</span></p>


</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you can't +1 an element like that

Answer (score 2):

You don't have an ID `#counter` on the page, and you need to get the `textContent` of `#count` and convert it to an integer to add a number to it.

This line

```
counter = document.getElementById("counter");
```

should be

```
counter = parseInt(document.getElementById("count").textContent);
```

```js
var $ = function(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
};
var counter;

function start() {
  var button = document.getElementById("button");
  window.addEventListener("click", count, false);
};

function count() {
  counter = parseInt(document.getElementById("count").textContent);
  counter = counter + 1;
  document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = counter;
};

window.addEventListener("load", start, false);
```

```html
<p><input type="button" id="button" value="button"></p>
<p> count: <span id="count">0</span></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it simply..

```js
    var clicks = 0;
    function onClick() {
        clicks += 1;
        document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
    };
```

```html
    <button type="button" onClick="onClick()">Click me</button>
    <p>Clicks: <a id="clicks">0</a></p>
```