# How are the times that a user presses the button counted?

Tags: javascript

I have thought to use a tag to write the value of the counter to it so that the information is not lost. How should I do it?

```js
function count() {
  var val = document.getElementById("write").value;
  if (val == "0") {
    var count = 0;
  }
  count++;
  document.getElementById("write").innerHTML = count;
}
```

```html
<button id="idButton" onclick='count'>Click here!</button>
<h1 id="write">0</h1>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API

Comment: Does this answer your question? [counting the number of times a button is pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42477001/counting-the-number-of-times-a-button-is-pressed)

Comment: Please don't modify the code in your question after it has has received answers. Your modifications may invalidate existing answers. If you have new questions about a new version of your code, post another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few things wrong here:

- `onclick='count'` will not do anything, you need to invoke the function: `onclick="count()"`, or better yet, bind an event handler from within your JavaScript, better separating script from presentation.
- `var val = document.getElementById("write").value;` doesn't work. An `h1` has no `value` attribute. You want `textContent`
- You only create an initialize `counter` when `val == "0"`. After each subsequent button press, your `if (val == "0")` check will fail, and `counter` will not be defined, so `counter++` will yield `NaN`.

A modern approach would store the state in memory, decoupled from the DOM, rather than reading the state from the DOM, casting it back to a number from a string.

Something along the lines of:

```js
let count = 0;
const el = document.getElementById('write');

document.getElementById('idButton').onclick = (event) => {
  el.textContent = ++count;
};
```

```html
<button id="idButton">Click here!</button>
<h1 id="write">0</h1>
```

Comment: Thanks meagar! It works perfect. I'm new to this, sorry for so many mistakes. ; )

Comment: @julian It's my pleasure to help, but please see the notes I left below your question and answer. Your question is meant to be fundamentally unchanged after you post it, and any answer you provide later should be directly related to the original question, not simply a new version of your code based on features not referenced by the original question.

Comment: Sorry if I bothered something. The changes I have been able to make have been with the intention of improving and not belittling your valuable help. Thank you very much really meagar.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
var num = 0;
function count() {
    document.getElementById("write").innerHTML = ++num;
}
```

```html
<button id="idButton" onclick="count()">Click here!</button>
<h1 id="write">0</h1>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can cast value to number and then just add plus 1 to it.

Change you onclick as `count()` instead of `count`

```
<button id="idButton" onclick='count()'>Click here!</button>
<h1 id="write">0</h1>
```

---

```
 function count() {
      var val = document.getElementById("write").innerHTML;
      var counter=Number(val)+1;

      document.getElementById("write").innerHTML = counter;
    }
```

Comment: It would not be a very good idea to rely on the `innerHTML` value. Setting a counter would be a better way.